# Appending a "0" to the beginning of a cell in a CSV file?

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, csv, formatting

To be specific, I've got a list of about 2000 FIPS codes (example: "8001007801") in a single column of a CSV file. All of these codes **should** begin with a 0, but by default Excel formats the cells to remove "0" values at the beginning of a cell that contains only numbers. I know how to format this when I'm **printing** but not when I'm **writing** to a file.

I need my script to go through the first cell in each row, place a "0" at the front of it, and then copy that row to a new output CSV. Here is what I have so far:

```
    import csv

    inFile = open("FIPS_original.csv", "r")
    reader = csv.reader(inFile, delimiter = ";", quotechar = '"')

    outFile = open("FIPS_appended.csv", "w")
    writer = csv.writer(outFile, delimiter = ";", quotechar = '"')    

    for row in reader:
        outRow = list(row)
        outRow[0] = outRow[0].zfill(11)
        writer.writerow(outRow)

    inFile.close()
    outFile.close()
```

All this script does at this point is copy the same values to the output CSV, but it does not actually append the "0". 
Can anyone help out with this? Please let me know if you need more information, and thanks in advance.

EDIT: I should note that when I use the print function to print my values in the Python IDLE, they come out formatted correctly. I should also note that I have unchecked the Excel setting that automatically formats text cells with no alphabetical characters as numbers, and I have also tried formatting all of the cells in both spreadsheets as numbers.

ANSWER: Turns out it was indeed a formatting issue in Excel. Changing the cell type to text does nothing even if you disable the option that automatically changes text cells with only numbers to number cells. What you have to do is custom format your cell to hold however many characters you need (which doesn't solve anything if all of the numbers in the column are different characters). This link explains how to do it: https://superuser.com/questions/88870/adding-a-zero-before-values-in-an-excel-spreadsheet-column

Thanks for all the help - once enough time has passed for me to post this as an answer to my own question I will.

Comment: @KevinL no I'm not trimming new lines, that's my full code. Do you think I should add a nested loop for field in row to fix that? And just use field[0] instead of row[0]? (I'm assuming that outRow[0] is calling the full row and not the first cell in the row)

Comment: Maybe add a few lines of example data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import csv

fn_in="/tmp/FIPS_original.csv"
fn_out="/tmp/FIPS_appended.csv"
with open(fn_in, "r") as inFile, open(fn_out, 'w') as outFile:
    reader = csv.reader(inFile, delimiter = ";", quotechar = '"')
    writer = csv.writer(outFile, delimiter = ";", quotechar = '"')    
    header=next(reader)
    writer.writerow(header)

    for row in reader:
        row[0] = row[0].zfill(11)
        writer.writerow(row)
```

The behavior you are describing is *probably* because csv is not parsing each column in each row into a list. Try putting in a print statement to make sure that your delimiter and quote characters are correct.

Comment: So this is interesting: I added a print statement in my loop to print each row and not only is there no delimiter (maybe because the list only has one value?), the values are also **correct** (i.e. they read ['08123002020'] instead of ['8123002020']). So maybe this has to do with the default CSV formatting? I should also mention that the only change I made to my original code at this point is adding the print statement.

Comment: I dunno. My example works for *me* with a simple test file and does correctly write out the data with the correct leading zeros. Using different quotechar may change this.

Comment: I used your exact code (minus the /tmp/) and it gives me the same result :-( . It must be something to do with the Excel formatting I would think.....I'll mess around with my delimiter and quote chars a bit. Thanks for the help.